# Error when trying to bulk create new-adgroup from csv file

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I' am trying to create a bunch of AD groups using New-ADGroup.
When I run the script I get the following error:

*New-ADGroup : Cannot validate argument on parameter 'GroupCategory'. The argument is null. Provide a valid value for the argume
nt, and then try running the command again.*

The script I' am running is:

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory

#Import CSV
$groups = Import-Csv '\\server\path\to\file\myfile.csv'


# Loop through the CSV
    foreach ($group in $groups) {

    $groupProps = @{

      Name          = $group.name
      Path          = $group.path
      GroupCategory = $group.category
      GroupScope    = $group.scope
      Description   = $group.description

      }#end groupProps

    New-ADGroup @groupProps
    
} #end foreach loop
```

My csv file and columns:
[my file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8TTZR.png)

I tried to swap the order of parameters, originally is was **name, path, scope, category, description** however, it returns the same error.

I read the documentation for New-ADGroup and the code seems right, so I' am kind of stuck right now.

I used this to create the script and .csv file: [https://activedirectorypro.com/create-active-directory-security-groups-with-powershell/](https://activedirectorypro.com/create-active-directory-security-groups-with-powershell/?unapproved=35535&moderation-hash=249d7907c2e66e4711264124f69b4f31#comment-35535)

Comment: Try opening the CSV file in notepad or by using `Get-Content` so you can see the actual raw content - make sure the delimiter is actually `,` (Excel tends to favor `;`)

Comment: Thanks for the reply :) Tried opening it as you said, and sure enough it is seperated by semicolon. Tried changing it to comma. But I still get an argument is null for 'GroupCategory' :(

Answer (score 0):

``
Import-Module ActiveDirectory

#Import CSV
$groups = Import-Csv '\server\path\to\file\myfile.csv'

## Loop through the CSV

```
foreach ($group in $groups) {

$groupProps = @{

  Name          = $($group.name)
  Path          = $($group.path)
  GroupCategory = $($group.category)
  GroupScope    = $$group.scope)
  Description   = $($group.description)

  }#end groupProps

New-ADGroup @groupProps
```

} #end foreach loop``

Comment: Didnt work, still get null for groupcategory :(

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution. As Mathias R. Jessen said it was the delimiter.

Fixed it by adding `-Delimiter ";"` at the end of `$groups = Import-Csv '\\server\path\to\file\myfile.csv'`

So it ended up like this:

```
$groups = Import-Csv '\\server\path\to\file\myfile.csv' -Delimiter ";"
```

Comment: Nice! Don't forget to accept your own answer (click the checkmark on the left) when the timer runs out :)